# How do I let users be able to view, update and delete their own content?

Tags: users, nodes

I want to let users view a list of their own content and also be able to edit or delete them same as "/admin/content" page.

However, giving access to edit and delete their own content can be achieved using Node Access Rules or setting the access to user type at Permissions tab.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way will be to use [Workspace module](https://drupal.org/project/workspace)

- Step 1:

  Visit http://drupal.org/project/workspace to download the latest version of "Workspace".

  - Step 2:

  Extract the files into a folders on your desktop. The folder will be called "workspace".

  - Step 3:

  Login to your site's files via FTP and navigate to /sites/all/. If there isn't a folder called /modules/ here, create one.

  - Step 4:

  Upload the "workspace" folder to /sites/all/modules/

  - Step 5:

  Go to Administer >> Site building >> Modules and enable Workspace. You'll need to check only one box.

  - Step 6:

  When your users login they'll see a link in the admin menu called "My Workspace". When they click on it they'll see a screen like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views). Create a view of content on your site and use table format, list the fields as listed in admin/content. Add a relationship to the content:author so as to get access to the user table. In contextual filters (arguments for drupal 6), add user:uid => provide default value => user id from logged in user. Add a page display to your view and optionally provide a normal menu entry (or do that with the menu system) and Save your view. Go to the page you created, you should see only the content you created. To be able to mass delete or perform other bulk operations on the content, use [Views Bulk Operations](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)